# Accessing Struct Layers Using Reference Operator

Tags: c

How can I cycle through the array using a for loop and the reference operator?

```
for (i = 0; i < university->size; i++)
    {
        if (university->arr->MarkA <= 100)
        {
            sum += university->arr->MarkA;
            count++;
        }
```

Where should I insert the i?

These are the structures:

```
typedef struct Student
{
    char *name;
    long ID;
    int MarkA, MarkB, HW;
}stud;

typedef struct University
{
    stud *arr;
    int size;
}Uni;
```

I used a function to create a University array

```
void build_Uni(FILE* in, Uni* university)
{
    int i = 0;
    stud temp;
    char Name[100];
    while (!feof(in))
    {
        fscanf(in, "%s%li%d%d%d", Name, &temp.ID, &temp.MarkA, &temp.MarkB, &temp.HW);
        i++;
    }
    university->size = i;
    rewind(in);
    university->arr = (stud*)malloc(university->size * sizeof(stud));
    if (university->arr == NULL) Get_Lost("Memory allocation failed!");
    else for (i = 0; i < university->size; i++)
        fill_Uni(in, university->arr + i);
}

void fill_Uni(FILE* in, stud* student)
{
    char Name[100];
    fscanf(in, "%s%li%d%d%d", Name, &student->ID, &student->MarkA, &student->MarkB, &student->HW);
    student->name = (char*)malloc((strlen(Name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (student->name == NULL) Get_Lost("Error allocatig memory");
    strcpy(student->name, Name);
}
```

In the main function I called the above functions to work on this structure

```
Uni university;
```

Comment: Please show all type declarations. The array you are referring to is not visible.

Comment: I accidentally posted without typing them and now I can't post for another 90 minutes

Comment: You cannot [edit] this question?

Comment: Just did. Still pretty new to this

Comment: There still is no visible array. can you show how the pointer to `stud`, named `arr` is initialised?

Comment: Please create a little demo program which sets up the environment of the code you are trying to write. I would expect to see either a definition of an array of stud, the address of which is written to `arr` or a call to `malloc()`. This is not the same as making a [mcve], but similar.

Comment: I'll edit again

Comment: It's a really long code want me to post all of it?

Comment: _Side note:_ The _reference_ operator is `&` (as in: `int i = 0; int *p = &i;`). The _dereference_ operator is `*` (as in: `int i = 0; int *p = &i; int j = *p;`). But, what you're using is the _structure dereference_ operator: `->` (as in: `foo->bar`)

Comment: If it very long code, then the answer is in the MCVE link (that part is similar): Make a shorter version which still demonstrates what you are asking about.

Comment: Yeah @CraigEstey the structure dereference operator is what I think he was getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I cycle through the array using a for loop and the reference
>   operator?

I think you mean the dereference operator `->` but referencing and dereferencing will have nothing to do with cycling through the array; that's what your for-loop is for.

> Where should I insert the i?

This:

```
for (i = 0; i < university->size; i++)
{
        if (university->arr->MarkA <= 100)
        {
            sum += university->arr->MarkA;
            count++;
        }
}
```

Should be this:

```
for (i = 0; i < university->size; i++)
{
        if (university->arr[i].MarkA <= 100)
        {
            sum += university->arr[i].MarkA;
            count++;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your original question, you should access it as follows:

```
University university;
 ...  
for (i = 0; i < university.size; i++) {

    if (university.arr[i].MarkA <= 100)
    {
        sum += university.arr[i].MarkA;
        count++;
    }
    ...
}
```

If `university` is of type `University*`, however, the code changes a little bit, since you then have to use operator `->` to access the `university`-members:

```
for (i = 0; i < university->size; i++) {

    if (university->arr[i].MarkA <= 100)
    {
        sum += university->arr[i].MarkA;
        count++;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This code is fine but it appears to me that in his question the for-loop he asked about will be inside a function that takes a pointer to a `university` struct

Comment: @bigwillydos: right; not sure if OP uses the loop inside main or inside a function to which `univerity` is passed as pointer. Extended the answer accordingly.